# i Have a java class and interface, i want if anyone extend my java class should implement interface

Tags: java

i Have a java class and interface, i want if anyone extend my java class should implement interface.  I want to force user to compulsarily implement interface.if it extend my java class.

Comment: You'll have to be a bit clearer than this.  You may want an abstract class.

Comment: Others might find it helpful if you include what you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn the superclass into an abstract one and let it implement your interface.
Then make the methods given by the interface abstract ones.
This in turn forces your child class to implement the methods the interface has unless the child class is an abstract one, too.

Comment: yeah but i dont want this way. I want to force user to extend interface in different class not in the same class